# Group Columns Through SQL Without Using The Pivot Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the following table.

```
Store, Code, Active 
1000, C, N  
1000, D, N  
1000, J, N   
1000, R, N   
2000, C, N  
2000, D, N  
2000, J, N  
2000, R, N  
2000, F, N  
3000, C, Y  
3000, D, Y  
3000, J, Y  
3000, R, Y  
4000, C, Y  
4000, D, Y  
4000, J, Y  
4000, R, Y  
4000, F, Y
```

I would like to change it in SQL so that it shows like this.

```
Store, CDJR, CDJRF 
1000, N, N/A  
2000, N/A, N  
3000, Y, N/A  
4000, N/A, Y
```

Keep in mind that there are thousands of rows like this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what is the reasoning behind the column calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the same value in column active for each row with the same store value (as shown in your sample data) we can use numbers as masks and then check for a sum of these and populate `cdjr` and `cdjrf` columns accordingly:

```
select
  store,
  case when sum(codeflag) = 1111 then max(active) else 'N/A' end as cdjr,
  case when sum(codeflag) = 11111 then max(active) else 'N/A' end as cdjrf
from (
  select
    store,
    case when code = 'C' then 1 
         when code = 'D' then 10
         when code = 'J' then 100
         when code = 'R' then 1000
         when code = 'F' then 10000
    end as codeflag,
    active
  from t
) t
group by store
```

Result:

```
 store | cdjr | cdjrf
-------+------+-------
  1000 | N    | N/A
  2000 | N/A  | N
  3000 | Y    | N/A
  4000 | N/A  | Y
```

If you can't assume the same value for active column, we need to replace `max(active)` with just `active` column value and include it in GROUP BY clause. This will result in multiple rows for each store value where there are more than one value within active column.